# how to pass sum values to a c++ program without using argv & argc

Tags: c++, bash

i have a simple program

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
      cout<<"Hello"<<endl;
      int a;
      cin>>a;
      if(a==0)
              cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
      else
              cout<<"No"<<endl;

     return 0;
}
```

and i wanna have a *.sh file in ubuntu that it pass "a" to my code automatically.
Please help me
thanks.

Comment: Can't just give it an argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a pipeline in the shell file:

```
echo 33 | your_program
```

The `|` tells the shell to send the stdout of the left-hand command to the stdin of the right-hand command....